# How to get item text from CheckedListBox to ListBox without repeating the before text? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox of 10 names A to J (it's a string but here I'm just using abc), and I want to make it so that every time a user check something, the text will be shown in the listbox simultaneously. I have tried this:

```
For i = 0 To chklistbxDrugAvailableList.Items.Count - 1
            Dim drugs As String = CType(chklistbxDrugAvailableList.Items(i), String)
            If chklistbxDrugAvailableList.GetItemChecked(i) Then
                listbxYourOrder.Items.Add(drugs)
            End If
           'drugs = nothing
Next
```

But when I check A,B,C the text in the Listbox got repeated like so:

```
A
A
B
A
B
C
```

I don't know why this is happening. I didn't declare `drugs` as an array. Even when I used the `drugs = nothing`, it still give repeated values.

What should I do? Sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: Simply clear the listbox before adding new items i.e before the loop  - `listbxYourOrder.Items.Clear()`.

Comment: @preciousbetine now nothing is showing up in the listbox. Besides, I want a list of all checked items. If I clear the listbox everytime, only 1 item will appear, right?

Comment: *"nothing is showing up in the listbox"*. You're supposed to clear it before the other code, not after. *"only 1 item will appear"*. How could that be the case when you have code that adds all the checked items?

Comment: @preciousbetine thankyou it works now. Can you answer so I can accept? And can I ask why use clear? The listbox already empty before I check the items.

Comment: well, try the answer below and accept that if it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do the whole thing:

```vb
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    'Clear the current ListBox contents.
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()

    'Get the indexes of the currently checked items.
    Dim checkedIndices = CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Cast(Of Integer)()

    'Add the current index to the list if the item is being checked, otherwise remove it.
    checkedIndices = If(e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked,
                        checkedIndices.Append(e.Index),
                        checkedIndices.Except({e.Index}))

    'Get the checked items in order and add them to the ListBox.
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(checkedIndices.OrderBy(Function(n) n).
                                           Select(Function(i) CheckedListBox1.Items(i)).
                                           ToArray())
End Sub
```

or like this:

```vb
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    'Get the indexes of the currently checked items.
    Dim checkedIndices = CheckedListBox1.CheckedIndices.Cast(Of Integer)()


    'Add the current index to the list if the item is being checked, otherwise remove it.
    checkedIndices = If(e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked,
                        checkedIndices.Append(e.Index),
                        checkedIndices.Except({e.Index}))

    'Get the checked items in order and add them to the ListBox.
    ListBox1.DataSource = checkedIndices.OrderBy(Function(n) n).
                                         Select(Function(i) CheckedListBox1.Items(i)).
                                         ToArray()
End Sub
```

The difference is that, because the second option uses data-binding, the first item in the `ListBox` will be selected by default.

The reason that it needs to be a bit verbose is that the `ItemCheck` event is raised before the item is checked or unchecked. For that reason, we need to get the currently checked items first and then either add or remove the current item, depending on whether the current item is being checked or unchecked.

EDIT:

Here's an option that doesn't require clearing the `ListBox`:

```vb
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(sender As Object, e As ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.ItemCheck
    Dim item = CheckedListBox1.Items(e.Index)

    If e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue with that is that the items will appear in the `ListBox` in the order you checked them, rather than the order they appear in the `CheckedListBox`. The other options keep the items in the same order in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question I would this:

```
   lstbxYourOrder.Items.Clear()
   For Each l As String In chklistbxDrugAvailableList.CheckedItems
         listbxYourOrder.Items.Add(l)
   Next
```